# Filter csv files and create a new set of .csv files with the data

Tags: batch-file, csv, batch-processing

I am looking to create a .cmd file which filters all the .csv files in a folder and then creates a set of .csv files with the results.

Here is the scenario.

There are many .csv files in a folder
The first column of data in the csv file contains a code `HH??????-XX,`
where `??????` could be any set of numbers and `XX` ranges from `01 to 48`

I would like the batch file to start XX at 01 and where `HH??????-01` is found it takes the row and puts the results in an output file called `-01.csv`

The code `HH` at the beginning could be different so it would have to also filter for `HH`

This is then repeated for each of the csv files in the folder.

The whole process is then repeated for `HH??????-02` and outputs the file to a csv called `-02.csv` and so on up upto `-48.csv`

I dont have very much - i am not an expert in this field at all, only in VBA

I obtained this template from the web which i thought i could improve on but i don't really understand how i can adapt this. I am not familiar with FOR loops

```
@echo off
del c:\Total.csv
Del c:\Final.csv

Type c:\BATTEST\*.CSV > c:\Total.csv

FOR /F "eol=- delims=~ tokens=1-5,6,7*" %%1 IN ( c:\Total.CSV ) DO IF %%4 EQ 456 ECHO  %%1 %%2 %%3 %%4 %%5 %%6 %%7 %%8 >> c:\Final.csv
```

Example rows in the .csv files are: (remembering that `HH` could be something different)

```
HH777777-01,A,500,200,10,11,12,13,15.2,17.9,26,B
HH236748-02,C,300,100,11,14,17,19,21.2,18.9,14,B
```

Each file has a header which is the same throughout and it would be good to have this header in the final output file.

The header is

```
Code,type,head,file,make,run,style,line,edge,model,letter,status
```

Comment: I believe some actual examples from the files would help people understand the requirement (all the `*`s and `XX`s are a little confusing).  Also, what do you have so far?  Are you familiar with `FOR` loops in batch?

Comment: @mbroshi thanks for the reply i have updated my post with more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Added a `target folder` and a cd command for a `source folder`.

This works here - test it on some sample files.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "target=d:\target\folder"
cd /d "c:\source\folder"
for /L %%a in (101,1,148) do (
    set num=%%a
    del "%target%\-!num:~-2!.csv" 2>nul
    >"%target%\-!num:~-2!.csv.txt" echo Code,type,head,file,make,run,style,line,edge,model,letter,status
)

for %%a in (*.csv) do (
    for /f "skip=1 usebackq delims=" %%b in ("%%a") do (
        for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=-," %%c in ("%%b") do (
           set "line=%%c"
           if /i "!line:~0,2!"=="HH" >> "%target%\-%%d.csv.txt" echo %%b
        )
    )
)
ren "%target%\*.csv.txt" *.
pause
```

Comment: How on earth did you do this foxidrive, this is absolutely amazing! Where can i learn this????

Comment: Can i ask one more question..how do i aim this at a particualr folder and the output files to another folder?

Comment: I cant fully understand your script but where does it say to look for files -01 to -48?

Comment: I edited the answer and added paths, but didn't test it.  the -10 to -48 comes from the data, in the second portion of the code, and the number is placed in token 2 which is `%%d` after being separated from the data by the delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /L %%a IN (101,1,148) DO CALL :header %%a

FOR %%f IN (q21956251*.csv) DO (
 FOR /f "usebackqskip=1delims=" %%a IN ("%%f") DO (
  FOR /f "tokens=2delims=-," %%d IN ("%%a") DO (
   FOR /L %%h IN (101,1,148) DO IF "1%%d"=="%%h" >>"-%%d.new" ECHO(%%a
  )
 ) 
)
FOR /L %%a IN (101,1,148) DO CALL :rennew %%a

GOTO :EOF

:header
SET "destfile=%1"
>"-%destfile:~-2%.new" ECHO(Code,type,head,file,make,run,style,line,edge,model,letter,status
DEL "-%destfile:~-2%.csv" 2>NUL
GOTO :eof
:rennew
SET "destfile=%1"
REN "-%destfile:~-2%.new" "-%destfile:~-2%.csv"
GOTO :eof
```

You don't explain what you mean by `The code HH at the beginning could be different so it would have to also filter for HH` - without an explicit specification, we start a guessing game.

This routine will first create a new set of files called `-nn.new` for n=01 to 48, write the header line to each and then **delete any existing -nn.csv**

The next step is to select all the `.csv` files - I selected `q21956251*.csv` for my testing. Each filename is assigned to `%%f` in turn.

Then `%%a` receives each line from the file `%%f`. The "usebackq`is required because`%%f`is quoted (in case of spaces in filenames). The`skip=1`means skip the first line (because it's a header) and the`delims=`means`assign the entire line`.

The next `for` looks at the line in `%%a` and selects the second (`tokens=2`) group of characters where `-` and `,` are both delimiters. This should select the `01` and '02' from your data. The numbers "101" to "148" are then compared with the concatenation of `1` with the number retrieved into `%%d`. When there's a match, the line `%%a` that was read from the file will be appended to `-%%d.new`

When all of the `.csv` files have been processed, the `:rennew` routine renames all of the `-nn.new` to `-nn.csv`.

It would be possible to process this sequence without the rename cycle. That's just the way I used.

Comment: This doesnt seem to work, it creates the csv files with the create name and puts the header in each, however it doesnt put the data inside the csv. Foxi's method works great. However i thank you putting in the effort to help :D We could look at why it doesnt work??

Comment: You did change `q21956251*.csv` to `*.csv` didn't you?

Comment: Hello Magoo, Just tested this it works equally well. Thank you for this alternative response

Answer (score 0):

Filtering CSVs with various conditions can be done with [EasyMorph](http://easymorph.com) (it has a free version). You might need to use parameters in EasyMorph to pass the `XX` code into a project.